# Tensorflow: efficient way to subtract a vector from the matrix

Tags: tensorflow

I have a MxN matrix and a length N vector. What I want to do is to subtract this vector from each of M rows of the matrix. The obvious way to do this is to tf.tile the vector, but this seems highly inefficient because of all the new memory allocation: tiling takes up to 4x as much time than the actualy subtraction.

Is there any way to do it more efficiently, or will I have to write my own operation in C++?

Comment: Shouldn't `x - y` just work because of broadcasting?

Comment: Well, actually just measured it, and broadcasting is only about 5% faster, is it how it's supposed to be?

Comment: `tile` is not as expensive as you thought. It's still linear in time except indeed it consumes more memory. So the timing doesn't surprise me, Not an expert in efficiency though.